# Accessing parent-child attributes in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two classes, namely `Person` and `Language`. Each **language** has a **creator** and an **updater** both who are from the `Person` class. I want to query attributes of the parent through the child and vice versa.

Person class

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String

  has_many :created_languages, class_name: 'Language', inverse_of: :created_by, foreign_key: 'created_by_id', autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :created_languages

  has_many :updated_languages, class_name: 'Language', inverse_of: :updated_by, foreign_key: 'updated_by_id', autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :updated_languages
end
```

Language class

```
class Language
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :content, type: String

  belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'Person', inverse_of: :created_languages, foreign_key: :created_by_id, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :created_by

  belongs_to :updated_by, class_name: 'Person', inverse_of: :updated_languages, foreign_key: :updated_by_id, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :updated_by
end
```

What I want to query in my Rails app is the following: i.e. in the Rails console:

```
ruby 2.0.0p451 > a = Person.create!(first_name: "Marco", last_name:"Reus")
ruby 2.0.0p451 > b = Language.create!(content: "German", created_by_id: a.id, updated_by_id: a.id)
ruby 2.0.0p451 > a.created_languages (now works)
ruby 2.0.0p451 > a.updated_languages (now works)
ruby 2.0.0p451 > b.created_by (now works)
ruby 2.0.0p451 > b.updated_by (now works)
```

I used to receive the below error. With the above code it was solved.

**Mongoid::Errors::AmbiguousRelationship:**
Problem: Ambiguous relations :created_languages, :updated_languages defined on Person.

**Summary:** When Mongoid attempts to set an inverse document of a relation in memory, it needs to know which relation it belongs to. When setting :updated_by, Mongoid looked on the class Language for a matching relation, but multiples were found that could potentially match: :created_languages, :updated_languages.

**Resolution:** On the :updated_by relation on Language you must add an :inverse_of option to specify the exact relationship on Person that is the opposite of :updated_by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also include inverse_of for all of them as such:

```
has_many :created_languages, class_name: 'Language', :inverse_of => :created_by

belongs_to :created_by, class_name: 'Person', :inverse_of => :created_languages
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Parts of it work. After adding `inverse_of: :created_by, foreign_key: 'created_by_id', autosave: true` to class `Person` I can now call `ruby 2.0.0p451 > a.created_languages`. However adding `inverse_of: :created_languages, foreign_key: :created_by_id, autosave: true`  to class `language` I still cannot call `ruby 2.0.0p451 > b.created_by`. Would you know what is wrong with the second part? thx

Comment: After reloading the edited version it now works. 1) I added `:inverse_of` and 2) I added `accepts_nested_attributes_for`  everywhere. The edited above code is functional. Thanks.